# How to change color of specific part of 3d Model using sceneform android

Tags: android, sceneform

I am trying to create sample app with sceneform SDK. I have successfully implemented 3d model into app. now I want to change the color of the 3D object of a specific portion, not the whole object.

this is what I tried

```
  private fun renderLocalObject() {

    skuProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    ModelRenderable.builder()
        .setSource(this, Uri.parse(localModel))
        .setRegistryId(localModel)
        .build()
        .thenAccept { modelRenderable: ModelRenderable ->
            skuProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
            addNodeToScene(modelRenderable)
        }
        .exceptionally { throwable: Throwable? ->
            var message: String?
            message = if (throwable is CompletionException) {
                skuProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                "Internet is not working"
            } else {
                skuProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE)
                "Can't load Model"
            }
            val mainHandler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
            val finalMessage: String = message
            val myRunnable = Runnable {
                AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Error")
                    .setMessage(finalMessage + "")
                    .setPositiveButton("Retry") { dialogInterface: DialogInterface, _: Int ->
                        renderLocalObject()
                        dialogInterface.dismiss()
                    }
                    .setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialogInterface, _ -> dialogInterface.dismiss() }
                    .show()
            }
            mainHandler.post(myRunnable)
            null
        }
}
```

private fun addNodeToScene(model: ModelRenderable) {
if (sceneView != null) {

```
        val renderableCopy = model.makeCopy()
        val changedMaterial = renderableCopy.material.makeCopy()

        changedMaterial.setFloat4(
            MaterialFactory.MATERIAL_COLOR,
            com.google.ar.sceneform.rendering.Color(Color.rgb(0, 51, 0))
        )


        renderableCopy.material = changedMaterial

        val transformationSystem = makeTransformationSystem()
        var dragTransformableNode = DragTransformableNode(1f, transformationSystem)
        dragTransformableNode?.renderable = renderableCopy

        for (child in dragTransformableNode.children) {
            Log.d("<>check","child $child")
        }

        sceneView.getScene().addChild(dragTransformableNode)
        dragTransformableNode?.select()


        sceneView.getScene()
            .addOnPeekTouchListener { hitTestResult: HitTestResult?, motionEvent: MotionEvent? ->
                transformationSystem.onTouch(
                    hitTestResult,
                    motionEvent
                )
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi any soultion for this?

Comment: Any solution yet?